# Form with multiple inputs. Show/hide label for input if filled or not

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, placeholder

I try to build form with placeholders moved to the top of input when input is focused, or filled. But I have a problem with multiple inputs on the same page. I don't know how to target specific one (used curently). Everything works good but my JS code affect all inputs on my page/form. So when I fill for example second input, all labels shows. I could use #id_name to do that but my page has lot's of forms and inputs, and I want to use this functionality around the entire website. How to target noly one input that is used curently?

This is my JS

```
    $('.h-placeholder').keyup(function() {
      
      // If input is not empty
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        // hide label
        $('.hideme label').css({"opacity": "0"});
      } else {
        // Otherwise show it
        $('.hideme label').css({"opacity": "1"});
      }
    }).keyup();
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<div class="gray-input hide-placeholder hideme">
<input class="h-placeholder" required type="text" id="zaw" name="zaw" placeholder="Zaw">
<label class="label-h-placeholder" for="zaw">Zaw</label>
</div><!--.gray input-->
<div class="gray-input hide-placeholder hideme">
<input class="h-placeholder" required type="number" id="wart" name="wart" placeholder="Wart">
<label class="label-h-placeholder" for="wart">Wart</label>
</div><!--.gray input-->
</div>  
</div><!--.row-->
```

And my CSS

```
.hide-placeholder{
    position: relative;
}
.hide-placeholder > label {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    background: #efeff3;
    padding: 0 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    left: 3%;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}
.hide-placeholder input:focus + label,
.hide-placeholder textarea:focus + label{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}
.hide-placeholder input:focus::placeholder,
.hide-placeholder textarea:focus::placeholder{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need:

```js
$('.h-placeholder').on("input",function(){$(this).next("label")
  .toggle((this.value=="" ||          
    this.type=="number" && +this.value == 0))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<div class="gray-input hide-placeholder hideme">
<input class="h-placeholder" required type="text" id="zaw" name="zaw" placeholder="Zaw">
<label class="label-h-placeholder" for="zaw">Zaw</label>
</div><!--.gray input-->
<div class="gray-input hide-placeholder hideme">
<input class="h-placeholder" required type="number" id="wart" name="wart" placeholder="Wart">
<label class="label-h-placeholder" for="wart">Wart</label>
</div><!--.gray input-->
</div>  
</div><!--.row-->
```

The script will make the label following the current input visible/invisible depending on the current length of the input. The "input" event also fires when you paste something into the input field through a mouse-action.

Comment: But this script make it not visible when value is not = 0. I want to keep the label visible when input has been filled.

Comment: Label is hidden by default using CSS

Comment: Yes, I tried to reduce your snippet "to the core". Maybe, I went too far. What I wanted to show was, that you can change the visibility of an element in a simple expression (`.toggle()`) without having to employ much else. I changed my answer again to keep the label showing if the value has a value of "0".

Comment: Hmmm, I found the sollution to do that using only CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/273ntk5s/2/ maybe this will be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hideme label')
```

selects every placeholder. Try

```
$(this).parent().find('label')
```